# Static or nonstatic getters/setters for static class variable in C++

Tags: c++, class, static, setter, getter

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class A {
private:
    static double X;
};

double A::X = 0.0;
```

The variable `A::X` really ought to be static, because all instances of `A` must, in the context I'm concerned with, share the same value of `A::X`.

Now, my question is whether to make getter and setter functions for `A::X` static.  They will be defined like this:

```
void A::setValue(const double x) {
#pragma omp critical
{
    if(x<0.0||x>1.0)
        // custom macro call to raise exception

    X = x;
}
}

double A::getValue() {
#pragma omp critical
{
    return X;
}
}
```

It seems to me that it makes absolutely no practical difference whether I add these getter and setter functions to `A` as static or as nonstatic member functions.  Is this right?

In this example, or more generally, what reasons might there be to prefer that such getter and setter functions be made static or nonstatic members of the class whose static member they control access to?

Comment: Using non-static accessor methods for a static member can be confusing.  If this will be used on a multi-threaded environment make static accessors and protect access to the data ( e.g. Use a mutex).  The static methods can also be called as if it were a non-static method like a.modifyStaticData()

Comment: @TimDave Assuming a single shared-memory threaded environment, and assuming only OpenMP is used for threading, then the critical section does, in fact, serve the same purpose as using a mutex (in the example above). Right?

Comment: I believe so, although I am not too familiar with omp

Comment: @TimDave OK, fair enough.  Your point is well taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. you can call static methods if no object have been declared
2. Your code is more readable: if you have a static method getA, you know that A is static

Comment: Yes, that's true.  In the context from which my question arose, I would never need to call the static method without any declared instances, so I didn't think about that.  But, yes, that's a good point.

Comment: static methods modify static members so when you read the .h you see a static method getA so you know that A is static

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try and split your reasoning between interface and implementation. If you need to call your setter/getter when no instance of the class has been instantiated, make them static. If you may need to override them make them non static and virtual.

I'm assuming you do need them both; this would be the case if your static data member is private only because you need to ensure its value meets some criteria. If it is involved in more complex logic you might want to reconsider your interface.

Comment: What you say sounds interesting, though I'm not sure I understand the second paragraph fully.  I read it as saying (among other things) that "if the only reason `A::X` is private is to ensure its value meets some criteria", then I should make the getter/setters nonstatic and virtual.  Is that what you mean? If so, I don't get your point.  (I do *not* need to override them ever, by the way.)

Comment: No, if your static data member could assume any value and you did not need to keep it consistent with other data members, you could just make it public and remove your setter and getter. If keeping it outside the 0.0 - 1.0 range is the only reason why you need your member functions, keep them static.